# How can I allow changing a cell only when another cell has a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where all the cells of column A contain a numerical value, and column B, which contains other values.

I would like with VBA (or other options, if there are alternatives) to control the change of the values in column A.

The user can change the cell A1 only if the cell B1 has a value equal to zero.
The same for the following rows, so the row A2 can be changed only if B2 is equal to zero, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next event code in the respective sheet code module, and play with changing:

```
Option Explicit

Private newVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.column = 1 Then
            If Target.Offset(, 1).Value <> 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoind triggering again the Change event
                  newVal = Target.Value
                  Application.Undo
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Waleed Yes, this is the normal way. It works in simple workbooks, but for complicated, some events are also triggered and VBA looses the UnDo list, raising an error. It is something happened to me and I delivered the safer way.

Comment: I would also like to say that I only observed that the above version worked OK and the one without the line in discussion didn't. I searched the internet to clarify the reason, but I did not find a clear, logical explanation. I only adopted the working solution...

Comment: @Waleed If I will tell you that in my testing environment (an workbook with about 200 sheets and many used events, **only the posted variant works** and the one without the code line in discussion **does not**, would you  believe me? **This is what is happening**! Like I said before, I cannot **exactly** understand why, **but this is the fact** and I wanted to share a version able to work in a very bushy environment, too.

Comment: Ok understood and surely believe you. I will delete all my previous comments (and this one) to not confuse any other ones.

Comment: @Waleed I do not think deletion is a good idea. Maybe somebody else asks himself the same question and I do not need to explain again the reason of that code line need... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data validation for this:

Select the range (ex: `A1:A10`)

Go to Data -> Data tools -> Data Validation

Choose the following options:

Allow "Custom"

Formula: `=B1:B10=0`

Comment: How can I prevent the user press CANC and delete that value?

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Selection Change: Restrict Column Access

- With the current setup (`A2`, `B`), the following will allow access to column `A` (more accurately, to `A2:A1048576`) only if a single cell is to be selected and the cell in the same row of column `B` is equal to `0`.
- Optionally, if you choose the out-commented *If* statement, it will also allow access if the cell in column `B` is empty.
- An empty cell is also numeric and equal to `0`. It isn't of type *Double* though, but of type *Empty*.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` (Not Into `ThisWorkbook` or Standard Module e.g. `Module1`)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TGT_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "B"
    
    Dim trg As Range
    With Me.Range(TGT_FIRST_CELL)
        Set trg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    ColumnOffset = Me.Columns(SRC_COLUMN).Column - irg.Column
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = irg.Offset(, ColumnOffset)
    
    If srg.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim sValue As Variant: sValue = srg.Value
        If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' write just if 0
        ' or:
        'If IsNumeric(sValue) Then ' write if 0 or empty
            If sValue = 0 Then Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    srg.Cells(1).Select
    
End Sub
```